# Save emojis using mysql connector 8 against server 5.6.22

Tags: java, mysql, emoji

I have a system which previously used:

- mysql server 5.6.22
- mysql connector 5.1.47
- the particular column was set to use utf8mb4_unicode_ci

And I was able to save and read emojis to/from that table column using java.

The mysql connector has now been upgraded to 8.0.12 for some reason, and the system complains when saving emojis,

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value:
>   '\xF0\x9F\x90\x91' for column 'name' at row 1

Anyone have idea how to fix this? Many thanks.

BTW, the JDBC connection string I'm using already has useUnicode=true and characterEncoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

That sheep needs utf8mb4, not utf8 throughout MySQL.  Not just the column, but also the connection.

For Java:

Add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL (or maybe it is =true and =utf8)

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

To use 4-byte UTF8 with Connector/J configure the MySQL server with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`. Connector/J will then use that setting as long as characterEncoding has not been set in the connection string. This is equivalent to autodetection of the character set.